# How would i open this from inside a .load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Hi I've got this fancy box script (below) what would i need to change it to, to make it work from inside some content that has been loaded with .load ? any helps much appreciated !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#various1").fancybox({   
    'padding' : '10',
    }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to simply call the fancybox() method again after adding new content.

This will re-bind the relevant items to use fancybox.

```
$("#various1").load(function(){
   // Do your load work here, adding items to the collection.
   $(this).fancybox([...]); // re-bind the fancybox
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Name your fancy function and call it after load.

```
$(document).ready(var1fancy);
function va1fancy() {
    $("#various1").fancybox({   
        'padding' : '10',
    });
}
```